# Why does this "if" statement get triggered?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been working for the past 5 hours on why does this if get triggered...

Let me show you the code and explain you :

```php
<?php

require_once "ConnectDB.php";
$link2 = $link;

$key = $posthwid = "";

$err = "";



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty($_POST["key"])){
        $err = "Thanks for the ip (" .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. "), have a good day! (1)";
    } 
    else{
        $key = trim($_POST["key"]);
    }
    $hwid = $_POST["hwid"];
    if(empty($err)){

        $sql = "SELECT hwid, idkey, length, created_at FROM money WHERE idkey = '" .$key. "'";
        $row = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($row) < 2){
                while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row)) {
                        if($result["idkey"] == $key) 
                        {
                            $err = "key";
                            if($result["hwid"] == "")
                            {

                                $err = "nohwid";
                                $sql2 = "UPDATE IceCold SET hwid = '" .$hwid. "' WHERE idkey = '" .$key. "'";

                                if(mysqli_query($link2, $sql2)){
                                    $hwid = $result["hwid"];
                                    mysqli_close($link2); 
                                    echo "debug";
                                }
                                else {
                                    $err = "Oops! Something went wrong. Contact the support.";
                                }

                            }
                            if ($hwid !== $result["hwid"]) {
                                $err = "Contact the support";
                            }
                            elseif($_SESSION["admin"] == true) {
                                //Do special stuff
                            } 
                            else {
                            ///do other checks

                                if($created_at > $date){
                                    $err = $hwid;
                                } else {
                                    $err = "The key date is too old, buy a new one.";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{

                            $err = "The key you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }  mysqli_close($link); 
                } else {
                    $err = "multiple entry, contact support";
                }   
            }


} else {
    $err = "Thanks for the ip (" .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. "), have a good day! (3)";
}

echo $err;

?>
```

So basically, I have this Connect DB file with a mysqli_connect called `$link` and I'm designing a liscence API for my program. My program will send a request with the "idkey" and "hwid" and is waiting for the hwid to come back. I have an entry in my sql databse with only a key registered and I've trying to make my program wotk by generating POST request with the id and a random hwid but I've found no success. If variables are weirdly moved around, It's because of the debugging.

Right now, with my current setup, I get the Contact the support response which I don't understand why?!? The request and the key are correct if I'm able to get this awnser.
It's probably a stupid mistake but I jsut can't figure it out...

Thanks in advance for your help

**Edit**: the `if` statement I'm referring to is this:

```php
if($hwid !== $result["hwid"])
```

There was a typo in the code that I fixed but it wasn't the issue,
as for the elseif, that would destroy the order of execution of the code and destroy the logic behind it(If that made sense).

Weirdly, after some tests, I found out that the second SQL request I send doesn't want to be executed ($sql2) and there is no error in httpd logs... Can you execute two requests? I tried to create $link2 but it doesn't change anything

*EDIT* : Found solution

```
if($result["hwid"] == "")
{
    $sql2 = "UPDATE money SET hwid = '" .$_POST["hwid"]. "' WHERE idkey = '" .$key. "'";

    if(mysqli_query($link2, $sql2)) {
        $newhwid = $_POST["hwid"];
        mysqli_close($link2); 
    }
    else {
        $err = "Oops! Something went wrong. Contact the support.";
    }
}
elseif ($_POST["hwid"] != $result["hwid"]) {
    $err = "Contact the support";
}

if($_POST["hwid"] == $newhwid || $_POST["hwid"] == $result["hwid"] ) {
/// do other checks
}
```

Comment: I count eight different `if` statements in your code; which one are you referring to?

Comment: @kaya3 The one before the else statment that sets $err to Contact the support

Comment: You're not setting `$newhwid` anywhere if `$row['hwid] != ""`

Comment: The question has gotten too many edits done. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

The condition before that one, `if($row['hwid'] = "")`, is an assignment. This code is changing the value of `$row['hwid']` to an empty string, causing the condition after it to be true. I assume you meant to write `==` to *test* if `$row['hwid']` is empty; otherwise it doesn't make sense to write this as an `if` statement.

By the way, it's not clear whether this `if` statement shouldn't be an `else if`. The rest of the branches here are `else if` (or `elseif`, which is the same in PHP), so you should consider whether you have missed out an `else` on this one too.

Comment: Questions which are simple typos should be answered in the comments and flagged to close as a typo.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, I wasn't aware of that. However, the OP says they've fixed this typo and it didn't solve the problem, so perhaps there is something else going on. (OP said this to me by proposing an edit to this answer, which should have been a comment.)

Comment: Unfortunately that happens quite often (people retype code instead of cutting and pasting), which is why it's more appropriate to do what I said, as that has made this answer incorrect.

Comment: @Nick, this isn't a typo error, I just forgot to copy my code again when I was testing -> Edit