# Php time and datatime object

Tags: php, datetime

So,
I know a lot of requests and question has been askeb about this subject but none really worked for my case... I'm working on a liscensing api with php (supposed to be easy) and I get a string date (2000-01-01) from my db and the length of the subscription. So I'm creating a DateTime Object with it using this :

```php
$created_at = date_create($result["created_at"]);
date_add($created_at, date_interval_create_from_date_string($result["length"]." days"));
```

But for some unknowed reason, It seems I can't get the current date in a DateTime object so I can just compare them with <>=. Even if I use `date_sub() or date_diff()` It still require two DateTime object. I'm really deseperate at this point so I figured I could ask for some help.
Hope I didn't miss anything obvious

Comment: Is this by any chance related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58667414/1415724)?

Comment: I resolved all the issues with my last question and made it work, and yes, it is the same project but absolutly not the same question @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'now' attribute,
`$today = new DateTime('now');` to get the current time.

Don't forget to set your timeregion in your php.ini to be able to get the right time.

And if you want to compare them, you can use `date_diff` and then 
`$var->format('%r')` to get the value. 
%r is going to be empty if the result is positive.
Good luck!